# Syntax tree with parent in Haskell

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to implement an AST in Haskell. I need a parent reference so it seems impossible to use a functional data structure. I've seen the following in an [article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.20.5286). We define a node as:

```
type Tree = Node -> Node
```

Node allows us to get attribute by key of type Key a.
Is there anything to read about such a pattern? Could you give me some further links?

Comment: And here's a nice [link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers).

Comment: Also keep an eye on ekmett's [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library. He's working on a lens-based zipper implementation integrated into the lib. For (I think) the next release.

Comment: @MrBones I know what zippers are. It's not what I need. I don't need to modify a tree, I want to put functions inside of a Node, and want these functions to depend on parent nodes. And I want to know more about this pattern.

Comment: Having a value dynamically change in response to other values changing is a form of reactive programming.  Check out a functional reactive library.  However, I caution you to consider that perhaps you are bringing an imperative mindset to a functional language, so it might help if you explain the problem context in case we might suggest more idionatic solutions.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Do you know what attribute grammars are? There's nothing to change. All I want is to calculate.

Comment: So you basically just want to tie the knot?

Comment: Actually I know how to do it. Lazy evaluation solves the problem. I need some more reading on this pattern.

Comment: Why do you need the parent reference? Or do you mean that the tree is actually a more general directed graph?

Comment: @PaulJohnson i want to resolve refences in a tree. That's why I need a parent.

Comment: You might want to look at UUAG from Utrecht University. There is a good manual for it (possibly slightly out of date) that is easier to work with than the attribute grammar system in the paper you link to. There have been more advanced attribute grammar libraries from Utrecht, but again UUAG is better documented. Note, though, that UUAG is a preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a pure data structure with cyclic self-references, then as delnan says in the comments [the usual term for that is "tying the knot"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot). Searching for that term should give you more information.

Do note that data structures built by tying the knot are difficult (or impossible) to "update" in the usual manner--with a non-cyclic structure you can keep pieces of the original when building a new structure based on it, but changing any piece of a cycle requires you to rebuild the entire cycle as well. Depending on what you're doing, this may or may not be a problem, of course.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov: You might find it interesting to browse the source of some standard libraries. Functions like `repeat x = xs where xs = x:xs` are defined in a way that ties the knot, so that using `repeat` creates a list with one "head" element that is its own tail. The naive `repeat x = x : repeat x` wouldn't do that.